# Is it possible to get Map value from application.properties file using springboot annotation @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to  fetch static key value pair data from `application.properties` file.Is it possible to do so with SpringBoot annotation `@Value`.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

**Example:**
`languageMap={'1'='English','2'='French'}`

```
@Value($("languageMap"))
Map<String,String> languageMap;
```

Comment: I guess this gets more intuitive if you chose the `application.yml`-format instead of `application.properties`. That format has 'dictionaries' and maps.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject Map using **@ConfigurationProperties** Annotation as mentioned in the docs.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml]

According that docs you can load properties:

> language.map[0]='English'
>
> language.map[1]='French'

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="language")
public class LanguageMap{

    private List<String> languages= new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getLanguages() {
        return this.languages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

application.properties:

```
languageMap[1]= English
languageMap[2]= French
```

Code, just use `@ConfigurationProperties` and setter method(setLanguageMap) is mandatory for the Map field, otherwise you don't get values.

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController("/myclass")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class TestControllerEx {

  Map<String, String> languageMap;

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity control() {

    System.out.println(getLanguageMap());

    return new ResponseEntity("success", HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  public Map<String, String> getLanguageMap() {
    return languageMap;
  }

  public void setLanguageMap(Map<String, String> languageMap) {
    this.languageMap = languageMap;
  }
}
```

output:

```
{1=English, 2=French}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using `@ConfigurableProperties`. You have to create a class to access those properties. Take a look at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot). In that example, see how `additionalHeaders` are being accessed. That will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@ConfigurableProperties` and restructure your properties file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("<prop-file-path>")
@ConfigurationProperties()
public class ConfigProperties {
    @Value($("languageMap"))
    Map<String,String> languageMap;
}
```

Properties File:

```
languageMap.1=English
languageMap.2=French
```